ffmpeg concat command Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 3 on filter Parsed_concat_0
The command "flutter ffmpeg" has been working perfectly fine so far, but now I'm receiving the following error message. Do you see any errors in the command?
"matching stream for unlabeled input pad 3 on filter Parsed_concat_0"
-y -i /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/26327694-3478-4DC9-B50A-E8D3B35F1918/Documents/camera/videos/REC_5FC1769A-5373-438B-A497-F10259C9F312.mp4 -i /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/26327694-3478-4DC9-B50A-E8D3B35F1918/Documents/camera/videos/REC_1690082E-558D-44D2-9103-5EFB3541F600.mp4 -filter_complex "concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/26327694-3478-4DC9-B50A-E8D3B35F1918/Documents/camera/videos/PmYLvxYAGc.mp4


Looks like your 2nd input does not have any audio.

Thanks for reply. Both video has audio and video stream too.
I have this error when the input us "very short" (under 1 second).  It does not have any sense, but it happens every time when the video is too short.
